# Как записать список слов текстом, а не зашифровано с помощью JSON

Tags: python, синтаксис

Производится запись списка в файла и его чтение из фала.
Мне нужно что бы в файле был текст, а не зашифрованная строчка типа такой

> ["\u0412\u044b\u0442\u044f\u0436\u043a\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u043d\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e
>   \u043c\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0436\u0430",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f
>   \u043f\u043e\u0441\u0443\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0435\u0447\u043d\u0430\u044f
>   \u043c\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043d\u0430",
>   "\u0413\u0430\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f
>   \u0432\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0447\u043d\u0430\u044f
>   \u043f\u0430\u043d\u0435\u043b\u044c",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u0441\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0430",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u0441\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0430",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u0441\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0430",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u0441\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0430",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0446\u043e \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   WOK-\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0438",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0446\u043e \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   WOK-\u043a\u043e\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043a\u0438",
>   "\u041b\u044e\u0431\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f\u043c
>   \u0438\u0442\u0430\u043b\u044c\u044f\u043d\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439
>   \u043a\u0443\u0445\u043d\u0438: \u043d\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0440
>   PastaPassion", "\u0417\u0430\u0449\u0438\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439
>   \u043a\u043e\u0436\u0443\u0445 Textile Protect \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   TDS16..",
>   "\u0422\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435
>   \u043d\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u044e\u0449\u0438\u0435
>   \u0434\u043b\u044f 3 \u0443\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043d\u0435\u0439",
>   "\u041c\u044f\u0441\u043e\u0440\u0443\u0431\u043a\u0430 +
>   \u0430\u0434\u0430\u043f\u0442\u0435\u0440 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u043a\u0443\u0445\u043e\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e
>   \u043a\u043e\u043c\u0431\u0430\u0439\u043d\u0430",
>   "\u041d\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0434\u043a\u0430-\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0430
>   \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0441\u044b\u0440\u0430 /
>   \u0448\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0430",
>   "\u041d\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0434\u043a\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0433\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f
>   \u0441\u043f\u0430\u0433\u0435\u0442\u0442\u0438",
>   "\u0414\u0435\u043a\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f
>   \u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0430; \u0446\u0432\u0435\u0442
>   \\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043b\u044c\",
>   "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f
>   \u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0438
>   \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043a\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0445
>   \u043f\u043e\u0441\u0443\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0435\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0445
>   \u043c\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043d"]

сам код

```
# запись списка res в файла
def save_file():
    print ('Запись нового списка:')
    f = open('list_new.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
    #f.writelines(res) 
    json.dump(res, f)
    f.close()
path = input('Запись нового списка - y, отмена записи - любая клавиша: ')
if path == 'y':
    save_file()
    path = 'n'

# чтение списка из  файла
res_nw = [] # новый списко
f = open('list_new.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для чтения
#f.writelines(res) 
res_nw = json.load( f)
print ('Список получен из файла:')
print(str(res_nw)) # печать нового списка
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

вот эту строчку надо дополнить

```
json.dump(res, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```